# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Underflow in restore - more restores than saves

Tags: android, ripple, rippledrawable

I am using `rippleeffect library` for my project. But in `Android Nougat and Marshmallow`, App crashes due to this library:

`compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'`

The error message is:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.test.testapp, PID: 17713
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Underflow in restore - more restores  than saves
>       at android.graphics.Canvas.native_restore(Native Method)
>       at android.graphics.Canvas.restore(Canvas.java:522)
>       at com.andexert.library.RippleView.draw(RippleView.java:170)
>        ........................
>        ........................

As far as the below link this is a known issue. https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect/issues/76 and I also tried so many solutions from stackoverflow but luck did favor so far!!!

What can be done to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you can fix this error by downgrading your - targetSdkVersion to 22 but i do not recommend to use that ! You don't need libraries to use ripple effect

Comment: This issue came in Android API Level 23 (Marshmallow). I updated the Library version to newest. They have solved the bug.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I faced the same issue and did not found a good solution for that.But If you

- Downgrade `targetSdkVersion` to 22 you can run it: meaning it does not crash! but I really *don't* recommend that.
- Try to compile it with compile this dependency ->`'com.github.emanzanoaxa:RippleEffect:52ea2a0ab6'`
- Call `canvas.save();` before every `restore()` is another suggestion from your link given that you can try
- You can also try to add that library inside your project and use it

https://codeload.github.com/traex/RippleEffect/zip/master (from the link you provided there are solutions that people have tried use them)

---

Or i suggest you to create them by yourself no libraries needed at all!

`Ripple` touch effect was introduced in Android 5.0 (API level 21) and the animation is implemented by the new `RippleDrawable` class.

General, ripple effect for regular buttons *works* by default in API 21 and for other touchable views, it can be achieved by *specifying*:

`android:background="?attr/selectItemBackground"`

for ripples contained within the view or:

`android:background="?attr/selectItemBackgroundBorderless"`

for ripples that extend beyond the view's bounds.

You can achieve the same in code using:

```
int[] attrs = new int[]{R.attr.selectItemBackground};
TypedArray typedArray = getActivity().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
int backgroundResource = typedArray.getResourceId(0, 0);
myView.setBackgroundResource(backgroundResource);
```

---

If you want to **customize** the ripple effect into a view,
you need to create a new `XML` file, inside the drawable directory.

Examples:

**Example 1**: An unbounded ripple

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#ffff0000" />
```

**Example 2**: Ripple with mask and background color

```
<ripple android:color="#7777666"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="#ffff00" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
</ripple>
```

**Example 3**: Ripple on top a drawable resource

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#ff0000ff">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_drawable" />
</ripple>
```

**How to Use:**
To attach your ripple xml file to *any view*, set it as background as following:
*assuming your ripple file is named `my_ripple.xml`. in exmple 1, 2 or 3*

```
<View 
    android:id="@+id/myViewId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/my_ripple" />
```

Comment: 'com.github.emanzanoaxa:RippleEffect:52ea2a0ab6' dependency worked for me.

Comment: I had 2 restore() for 1 save(). Adding a 2nd save did it. Thanks a lot for the hint.

Answer (score 14):

they fixed the bug :P 
[RippleEffect](https://github.com/patrickpissurno/RippleEffect/)

Comment: very nice @Nuke

Comment: It is still coming.

Answer (score 1):

Check your code again. You probably have an extra **.restore()** method somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I blur image inside `OnScroll` (I scroll a view and blur in a loop). I initialized `canvas` so:

```
val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
// OnScroll:
    scroll.draw(canvas)
    blurImage(bitmap)
```

It lead to the exception. So, I moved `val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)` inside a loop:

```
val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
// OnScroll:
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    scroll.draw(canvas)
    blurImage(bitmap)
```

Later I removed blurring outside of the loop, so that canvas wasn't created in the loop anymore.